# Rails get collection of parents from children

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models/relationships:

```
class Directory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :directory
  geocoded_by :full_address
end
```

`Location` uses the `geocoder` gem.  Each directory entry has a location, along with directory information (contacts, website, etc).

In `directory#index`, I would like to show locations near the user's search location.  So far I have:

```
def index
  if params[:search].present?
    @directories = Location.near(params[:search], 50, :order => :distance).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  else
    @directories = Directory.order(:name).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
  end
end
```

How can return a collection of directory (parent) entries corresponding to locations (children)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
Directory.joins(:locations).where(locations: { id: Location.near(params[:search], 50, :order => :distance) })
```

This will generate a query similar to this:

```
SELECT `directories`.* 
FROM `directories` 
INNER JOIN `locations` ON `locations`.`directory_id` = `directories`.`id` 
WHERE `locations`.`id` IN (SELECT `locations`.`id` FROM `locations` WHERE "your search query here" )
```

**EDIT**: Or you can move the `Location` query right into `INNER JOIN` clause:

```
location_query = Location.near(params[:search], 50, :order => :distance).distinct.select(:directory_id)
directories = Directory.joins("INNER JOIN (#{location_query.to_sql}) loc ON loc.directory_id = directories.id")
```

I believe the queries above are better than direct mapping directories, i.e.

```
directories = Location.near(params[:search], 50, :order => :distance).
  paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10).map(&:directory)
```

because in my query you can apply pagination at the right level (directories), but here you apply it to locations. This is not so good, because if some locations belong to same directory, you'll end up with duplicate directories (if you forget to add `.uniq` at the end of your query) or a shorter directories list (if you don't forget about `.uniq` :) ).

Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks Alexey for your detailed answer but it does not work for me.  I suspect it is because I have a `has_one` relation between parent and child, so there is no `locations` association.  I tried making it `location` but that did not seem to help.  I think I'll stick with my approach (not so bad since I have a one to one relationship between parent and child) but hopefully your answer can help someone else.

Comment: Oh, it's a pity. I don't think that `has_one` is a problem, maybe it's `geocoder` generates some heavy query that I am not aware about. Nevertheless, I'm glad you've solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, not strictly an answer to my question, but since other answers have not been forthcoming, I took a nap and then realized that this was a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for me.

Rather than generating a collection of parents (directories), I just did what the geocoder gem wanted to do and generated a collection of locations.  Then, in my view, I just used the `directory` parent association to get to each corresponding directory.

Works perfectly.